# Moving Firebase (GoogleService-Info.plist & API Key) to Production on iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-mlkit

My question revolves around how to transition the information in the GoogleService-Info.plist file to Production (i.e. deployed on the iOS App Store)?

My predicament is pretty simple: I am developing a native iOS app in Swift. I am using Firebase ML Kit (Google Cloud Vision API). When I first set up my project in Firebase, I was prompted to download the GoogleService-Info.plist file, which I did. It is on the Desktop on my local computer, and all my local development works fine.

But, now I am ready to deploy this app to the App Store. Obviously, the App Store app is not going to fetch the credentials from my local Desktop. I am confused on how to transition my credentials to Production. I have read all of the Google Cloud docs (Securing API Keys, Service Accounts, etc.) but I have not found a simple, well-explained solution on how to approach this. If you are able to explain this to me as opposed to link to one of these resources that would be incredibly helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: The Plist file should be added to your iOS project and not alone on your local desktop.

Answer (score 1):

So, already you have a iOS project configured for GCV API. If the FCM development account and production account are same, the GoogleInfoServiceInfo.plist going to be same. So no worries. You can move to production with same file.

If production account is different, in the new production FCM account you have to configure the iOS app in the FCM API console for accessing the GCV API, download the plist file and replace it with the old one in same path. It should work perfectly.

Make sure to backup your old plist file before replacing with new one.

Comment: But by including the GoogleService-Info.plist file in the project, I am pushing it to GitHub, where it shouldn't be. All the Google Cloud docs say not to embed the GoogleService-Info.plist (specifically, the API_KEY contained within this file) to source control, which obviously makes sense.

Comment: Skip the files that you don't want to push it to repository.